# R and ggplot2: scale_x_continuous(trans = "log") with tick labels that are not in logs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot with `ggplot2` that has a x-axis in logs but with the x tick labels not in logs. To make it clear:

Suppose there is some x value 10. Since I use `scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")` it would appear as 2.3 on the x axis (`log(10) = 2.302585`). But instead I want that the number 10 appears since I only use `scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")` in order to improve the comparability of two density plots, that are very skewed.

Comment: You can misrepresent the x-axis tick labels directly via the `labels` parameter.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Could you give an example of how to specify the `labels` option in `scale_x_continuous`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1457051+%5Br%5D+scale_x_continuous+label

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I know that I can write `scale_x_continuous(labels = c(...))` in order to set tick labels manually. But what I want is (see my example from above) to place a tick label at `x = 2.302585` with the tick label `10`. I could not figure that out by looking at your examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a bit confused at what you're really after. Perhaps this will help you see what's going on underneath the covers in ggplot2. Also, `log()`, `trans="log"` !== `log10()`, `trans="log10"`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1492)
df <- data_frame(x=abs(rnorm(10) * 100) + 1,
                 y=seq(0, 1, length.out=10))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
gg <- gg + geom_vline(xintercept=10)

gg1 <- gg + scale_x_continuous()
gg2 <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(10, 50, 100, 150))
gg3 <- gg + scale_x_continuous(trans="log")
gg4 <- gg + scale_x_continuous(trans="log", breaks=c(10, 50, 100, 150))

grid.arrange(
  gg1,
  gg2,
  gg3,
  gg4,
  ncol=1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example and your patience. Before, I did not realize that the tick labels always refer to the actual scale (not the one in logs). I come frome Stata and there you have to tell the program explicitly to do that.